How to commit a local directory as a new subdirectory to an existing repository
I have a single Git repository containing scripts and whatnot, i.e. https://example.com/scripting
Each set of scripts is supposed to be located in a subdirectory https://example.com/scripting/proj1,  https://example.com/scripting/proj2, etc.
On one client machine proj1 is supposed to be used, proj2 on another client etc., i.e.

client1:/home/user1/proj1
client2:/home/user2/proj2

I have started a new project called "proj3" on yet another client machine.

client3:/home/user3/proj3

I want to include this folder "proj3" into the "scripting" repository, i.e. as https://example.com/scripting/proj3.
How?
It would be easier to create separate repositories I guess. However the scripting is related, I'd love to keep it together.
What is the easiest/best/most supported way?
This is not about adding an existing Git repository as a submodule of the repository that I'm working on. Locally, I don't have a repository at all. I can of course git init . in proj3. But then I want to include it into the existing repository as https://example.com/scripting/proj3.

Unlike SVN and some other version control systems, Git repository is only able to track all subdirectories at once. It is not able to clone only "proj1" to first machine and "proj2" to second machine, all users will have "scripting" directory with all projects. So you need to clone the repository to add a new proj3 there.
